# Nlohmann not installing to /usr/local/include

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My `vmImage` is `'ubuntu-latest'`.

When my build comes to `nlohmann` I get the following error:

```
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include
CMake Error at libraries/nlohmann_json/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "/usr/local/include": Operation not
  permitted.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  libraries/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
```

It works fine locally and also on the Windows and MacOS `vmImage` pipelines, so I am assuming this is some type of permissions issue/setting with `DevOps`?

The `yaml` file is as follows:

```
# Starter pipeline
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'install python 3.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'install opengl'
  inputs:
    script: 'sudo apt-get -y install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev'
    failOnStderr: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'install sdl'
  inputs:
    script: 'sudo apt-get install -y libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libsdl2-net-dev'
    failOnStderr: true

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'update google gpg key'
  inputs:
    script: 'wget -q -O - curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -'
    failOnStderr: false

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'install gcc 10'
  inputs:
    script: 'sudo apt-get update && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install gcc-10 g++-10'
    failOnStderr: true

- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'run build.py'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build.py'
    failOnStderr: false
```

Comment: Could you share your yaml file? What task did you run?

Comment: I have added the `yaml` file. The task itself is running a `Python` script which runs `CMake`. The build works fine on the Windows and MacOS `DevOps` pipelines.

Comment: Could you set system.debug to True to check whether there is more log? How's the Python script like?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I enabled debug info, but it didn't reveal anything it seems. I ended up disabling the install step as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I disabled the install step of `nlohmann json` by doing the following before I added the subdirectory:

```
set(JSON_Install OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")
```